# P-complete problem due to logspace reductions. What does it mean?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, reductions, space-complexity

> Prove that problem $A$ is complete in $P$ due to reductions
>   computed in logarythmic space

How to understand this statement ? What should be shown ? For me:
1. $A$ is in $P$.
2. Each problem  in $P$ can be reduced in logspace to $A$

Can I use transitivity of logspace in this exercise  ?

Comment: Your understanding of the definition of "complete with respect to reductions computed in logarithmic space" is correct.

Comment: As to your other question, whether you can use transitivity of logspace in this exercise, this is a question to whoever gave you the exercise; we cannot possibly answer it. In published math you are allowed (and encouraged) to use whatever correct facts you can cite.

Comment: Question contains complete answer; voting to close.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I meant: Can I use trick similar to logspace transitivity ?  Some machine $C$ capture readings from tape (field $i$) of machine $K$ and in logspace provides field $i$. So the difference is that here $K$ works in $P$, no logspace. Is it also ok in this case use this trick ?

Comment: You need to give a logspace reduction from a P-complete problem (with respect to logspace reductions) to A.